# Database messaging for multiple model types - user, group, global

Tags: database, database-design, orm, django-models, relational-database

I want to implement an alert messaging system, in a website, that will show a message to either multiple **users**, multiple **groups** (different DB representation), or **globally** to all users.

What would a good database relationship for this behavior look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is where I would start based on the information you've given...

A table for the alert messages to be sent out...

```
alerts
    id      unsigned int(P)
    message text

+----+---------------------+
| id | message             |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | The sky is falling! |
|  2 | Some other message  |
| .. | ................... |
+----+---------------------+
```

A table to hold information about all the groups...

```
groups
    id          unsigned int(P)
    name        varchar(20)

+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Group A |
|  2 | Group B |
| .. | ....... |
+----+---------+
```

A table to associate groups and alerts. Each column is a foreign key to it's respective table and together they form a primary key - this will make sure no group is every associated with the same alert more than once.
In my example data we see that Group A is signed up for both "The sky is falling!" and "Some other message" messages while Group B is only signed up for "Some other message" alerts.

```
groups_alerts
    alert_id        unsigned int(F alerts.id)--\_(P)
    group_id        unsigned int(F groups.id)--/

+----------+----------+
| alert_id | group_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        2 |
| ........ | ........ |
+----------+----------+
```

A table for user information...

```
users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)
    password        varbinary(255)
    ...

+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | username | password | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | ... |
|  3 | john     | ******** | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

A table that associates users with alerts. The keys follow the same logic as those in the `groups_alerts` table. In my example data we see that `john` is signed up for the "The sky is falling!" message.

```
users_alerts
    user_id     unsigned int(F users.id)---\_(P)
    alert_id    unsigned int(F alerts.id)--/

+---------+----------+
| user_id | alert_id |
+---------+----------+
|       3 |        1 |
| ....... | ........ |
+---------+----------+
```

And finally we need to associate users with groups. The keys follow the same logic as those in the `groups_alerts` table. In my example data we see that `bob` is a member of `Group A` and `mary` is a member of `Group B`.

```
users_groups
    user_id     unsigned int(F users.id)
    group_id    unsigned int(F groups.id)

+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       2 |        2 |
| ....... | ........ |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. What about global messages?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean - since global messages go to all users you would just select all users in the `users` table and send them the message. I suppose if you wanted to you could create a `group` "Global" and enter records in the `groups_alerts` table for the global messages.

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating those linking records for every used in the system - that's what I mean.

Comment: @Dor - you wouldn't have to link them to the users, just link the alerts to the `Global` group. And I'm not sure you'd even have to have a Global group - it really depends on how you've got your application set up.